# Why Node js doesn't see files in node_modules folder

Tags: node.js, express

I added to my html page:

```
<script src="/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
```

but i have error:

> GET http://localhost:30003/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js 404
>   (Not Found)

i tried to add into my server file:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/'));
```

and it doesn't help.
Please tell me how i can solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this:

```
app.use('/scripts', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/angular/'));
```

And then in your HTML you can get it like this:

```
<script src="/scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it is working, thanks